# float between 0-1 to int 0-17 issue

Tags: java

i got this seemingly simple task in computer class that has proven itself to be harder than i though: the program gets a random float between 0 - 1 that then i need to turn into an int between 0 - 17 not including 0 & 17 (sixteen possible values). so i started by making a simple for loop which didn't really work so i went and hard coded it:

```
public static float step(float input){
    if(input < (1/16 * 1)){
        return 1;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 2)){
        return 2;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 3)){
        return 3;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 4)){
        return 4;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 5)){
        return 5;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 6)){
        return 6;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 7)){
        return 7;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 8)){
        return 8;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 9)){
        return 9;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 10)){
        return 10;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 11)){
        return 11;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 12)){
        return 12;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 13)){
        return 13;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 14)){
        return 14;
    }else if(input < (1/16 * 15)){
        return 15;
    }else{
        return 16;
    }
}
```

but for some reason that i can just not find it returns always 16! could anyone help me? (JAVA please)

Comment: what is your input value?

Comment: a random float that is 0 <  x < 1 for example 0.72705436 or 0.44382495 or  0.90334386 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a mapping function might help you write less code ;)

```
public static float map(float value, float smallestValue, float largestValue, float smallestReturn, float largestReturn) {
    return smallestReturn + (largestReturn - smallestReturn) * ((value - smallestValue) / (largestValue - smallestValue));
}
```

This function takes a value -> a float between 0 and 1 in your case.
You have to specify a range of the value, smallest value = 0, largest value = 1
Then you give it the range of the return : 1 to 16.

```
(int) map( randomGeneratedNumber , 0 , 1 , 1 , 16 );
```

Hope this will fit your needs!

Answer (score 6):

notice that using the value only, `1/16` for example, creates an integer division which will result in the value `0` in this case. So basically every statement will check if the value is 0. To get a correct result you should change the condition either to `1.0/16` or `1d/16`, or `1f/16` as a representation for float, since `1d` represents a double.

Answer (score 6):

Hint #1: 1/16 is the integer zero.

Hint #2: If you multiply input by ?? and convert it to an integer, what do you get?  ( No, you don't need a chain of `if` statements .... )

Answer (score 3):

The result of an Integer division is always an Integer.
Change either or both to a double (or a float) and you are good to go.

As an example:

```
System.out.println("1/16: " + (1/16));
System.out.println("1.0/16: " + (1.0/16));
System.out.println("1/16.0: " + (1/16.0));
System.out.println("1.0/16.0: " + (1.0/16.0));
```

Runnable version for the lazy:
http://ideone.com/jecgGP

Answer (score 2):

Problem with

```
(1/16 * 1)//result is int zero
```

use

```
 ((float)1/16 * 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float  max = 16;
max = max / randomClamped;
int retval = (int)max % 17;
```